# Display only a single state with ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

Is there a simple way to display only a single state?  For example

```
qmap("Texas", zoom=6)
```

produces

[image]

which obviously also includes all of Oklahoma, most of New Mexico, etc...is there a way to "mask" the surrounding states (and Mexico) to display only Texas?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you need to tell `ggmap` where Texas is. Typically you'd do that using a shapefile. See *e.g.*

- [R: ggmap – Overlay shapefile with filled polygon of regions](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/11/17/r-ggmap-overlay-shapefile-with-filled-polygon-of-regions/)
- [Plotting Choropleths from Shapefiles in R with ggmap](http://www.everydayanalytics.ca/2016/03/plotting-choropleths-from-shapefiles-in-R.html)